# How can I fix this segfault when starting xorg using the amdgpu driver?

Tags: xorg, gentoo, amd-graphics

Here is the error I get when executing startx:

```
[ 73398.822] (EE) 
[ 73398.822] (EE) Backtrace:
[ 73398.823] (EE) 0: /usr/bin/X (xorg_backtrace+0x4a) [0x58f2ea]
[ 73398.823] (EE) 1: /usr/bin/X (0x400000+0x192f99) [0x592f99]
[ 73398.823] (EE) 2: /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x7fdba3ac1000+0x14aa0) [0x7fdba3ad5aa0]
[ 73398.823] (EE) 3: /usr/lib64/xorg/modules/drivers/amdgpu_drv.so (0x7fdba02c6000+0xf09a) [0x7fdba02d509a]
[ 73398.823] (EE) 4: /usr/bin/X (BlockHandler+0xb1) [0x4427d1]
[ 73398.823] (EE) 5: /usr/bin/X (WaitForSomething+0x91) [0x58cd91]
[ 73398.823] (EE) 6: /usr/bin/X (0x400000+0x3db9a) [0x43db9a]
[ 73398.824] (EE) 7: /usr/bin/X (0x400000+0x41da8) [0x441da8]
[ 73398.824] (EE) 8: /lib64/libc.so.6 (__libc_start_main+0xee) [0x7fdba3719e5e]
[ 73398.824] (EE) 9: /usr/bin/X (_start+0x2a) [0x42ba1a]
[ 73398.824] (EE) 
[ 73398.824] (EE) Segmentation fault at address 0x10
[ 73398.824] (EE) 
Fatal server error:
[ 73398.824] (EE) Caught signal 11 (Segmentation fault). Server aborting
```

This is after updating a gentoo build.

Comment: Show us what you did. We need context not just error messages. (If the answer is no, then what is the question?)

Comment: This is the result of running the startx command.  The full xorg log file is here: https://pastebin.com/SzhZdEez

Some more context is that Xorg was working with my graphics card prior to rebuilding world - this is a gentoo build with multiple displays.